# Facebook App - Works great in everything but IE (two issues)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook

My brains a bit dead after the past 72 hours coding this project; hoping one could help two of the issues I'm having.

The app -> (url redirects to facebook) http://www.myfbcourses.com and if that doesn't work the direct url is http://apps.facebook.com/myfbcourses/

Now, in Safari/FireFox/Chrome this app works perfect. Just not in IE. My two issues:

1) When I invoke Jquery's Ajax, it doesn't show the content returning i.e. Pretty basic code, I don't know why it returns nothing on IE though.

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "call.php",
           data: "i=postTopic&cid="+i+"&comments="+comments+"&title="+title,
           success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
           }
         });
```

2) In IE; Even after authorizing / and fb-logging-in it doesn't seem it's authenticated.  I think in IE8 it kept looping the redirect to the page.. No idea

Would love the help! Thank you!

Comment: I've determined some issues; I think #2 is now fixed.  and #1 has to do with JS ("Length"). I think I can finish the rest here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue... Don't forget to include `type=text/javascript` in your code

Comment: If you are using HTML5 you do not need that, just for future reference.

Comment: That's correct, but If I recall this project, IE8 required type=text/javascript, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's an AJAX issue, I'm assuming your file is not hosted in the same server than your ajax call. So instead you have to use [JSOP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/).

So then try:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "call.php",
           data: ({"i" :postTopic, "cid" :i, "comments" : comments, "title" : title}),
           success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
           }
         });
```

Comment: Actually it is on the same server; it looks like it's just JS being thrown off by "value.length"